# Why won't my select appear with an option when created with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function showProperties() {
  const forButton = document.createElement('select');
  forButton.setAttribute('type', 'text')
  toolresult.appendChild(forButton)
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('value', 'Arial')
  forButton.appendChild(option)
}
```

This doesn't seem to create the dropdown, even though I created a option element that was appended inside the select, there is no option for Arial.

```js
const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');

const siteDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
const buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
const toolresult = document.getElementById('toolresult');
const item = document.getElementById('item');
// const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');


/* Popup */

const myStuff = prompt('Enter \'columns, rows\' NOTE: 5,20 is recommended on computer, refer to documentation.');

if (myStuff !== '' || myStuff.includes(',') === true) {
  const myStuffArr = myStuff.split(',');
  
  console.log(myStuffArr);
  
  window.amountOfColumns = myStuffArr[0];
  
  window.amountOfRows = myStuffArr[1];

} else {
  window.amountOfColumns = 5;
  
  window.amountOfRows = 20;
}

/* Functions */
const itemVisible = document.getElementById('itemVisible');

function changeItem(test) {
  itemVisible.value = test.slice(test.indexOf('t') + 1, test.length);
}
function showProperties() {
  const forButton = document.createElement('select');
  forButton.setAttribute('type', 'text')
  toolresult.appendChild(forButton)
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('value', 'Arial')
  forButton.appendChild(option)
}

var counter = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < window.amountOfRows; x++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < window.amountOfColumns; i++) {
    const myNewElement = document.createElement('input');
    myNewElement.width = siteDocument
    myNewElement.style.fontSize = '2vh';
    counter++
    myNewElement.setAttribute('id', 'myNewElement' + counter)
    console.log(myNewElement.id);
    myNewElement.addEventListener("focus", function doFunctionStuff() {
      changeItem(myNewElement.id)
    }); 
    sheets.appendChild(myNewElement)
    document.getElementById("sheets").style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + window.amountOfColumns +", 1fr)";
  }
}
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var z = 0; z < inputs.length; z++) {
   inputs[z].style.height = "calc((50vh/" +window.amountOfRows +") - 3px)";
   //inputs[z].style.maxHeight = "calc((80vh/20) - 100px)";
}

/* Fix Issues OR Bugs */
const submitFormula = document.getElementById('submitFormula');

submitFormula.style.fontSize = '1vw';

submitFormula.style.width = '8em';
submitFormula.style.height = '1.5em';

/* Stuff Extra */
/* 

/*  /* Download Excel File

var A = [['n','sqrt(n)']];

for(var j=1; j<10; ++j){ 
    A.push([j, Math.sqrt(j)]);
}

var csvRows = [];

for(var i=0, l=A.length; i<l; ++i){
    csvRows.push(A[i].join(','));
}

var csvString = csvRows.join("%0A");
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' +  encodeURIComponent(csvString);
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'myFile.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

*/
```

```css
#titletext {
  font-size: 5vh;
}

#sheets {
  display: grid;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttons > button {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 4vh;
  font-size: 2vh;
}
#itemVisible {
  width: 8vw;
}
#enterFormula {
  width: 8vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup"></div>
    <h1 id="titletext">Excel Sheets</h1>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="" onclick="">File</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Insert</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Page Layout</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Formulas</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Review</button>
      <button id="" onclick="showProperties()">Properties</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Developer</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Help</button>
    </div> <br>
    <div id="toolresult"></div>
    <div id="item">
      <input id="itemVisible" disabled></input>
      <input id="enterFormula"></input>
      <input type="submit" id="submitFormula"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="sheets" onchange="getItem()"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Snippet if you need it.

Comment: did you append `forButton` to the document?

Comment: @Nick yes, it was appended to toolresult which is a div I didn't include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below.  I have changed the line document.getElementById('toolresult').appendChild(forButton) and how you add value amd html to the option.

```
function showProperties() {
  const forButton = document.createElement('select');
  document.getElementById('toolresult').appendChild(forButton)
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = 'Arial';
    option.innerHTML = 'Arial';
  forButton.appendChild(option)
}
```

full code below

```js
const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');

const siteDocument = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

const popup = document.getElementById('popup');
const buttons = document.getElementById('buttons');
const toolresult = document.getElementById('toolresult');
const item = document.getElementById('item');
// const sheets = document.getElementById('sheets');


/* Popup */

const myStuff = prompt('Enter \'columns, rows\' NOTE: 5,20 is recommended on computer, refer to documentation.');

if (myStuff !== '' || myStuff.includes(',') === true) {
  const myStuffArr = myStuff.split(',');
  
  console.log(myStuffArr);
  
  window.amountOfColumns = myStuffArr[0];
  
  window.amountOfRows = myStuffArr[1];

} else {
  window.amountOfColumns = 5;
  
  window.amountOfRows = 20;
}

/* Functions */
const itemVisible = document.getElementById('itemVisible');

function changeItem(test) {
  itemVisible.value = test.slice(test.indexOf('t') + 1, test.length);
}
function showProperties() {
  const forButton = document.createElement('select');
  document.getElementById('toolresult').appendChild(forButton)
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = 'Arial';
    option.innerHTML = 'Arial';
  forButton.appendChild(option)
}

var counter = 0;

for (var x = 0; x < window.amountOfRows; x++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < window.amountOfColumns; i++) {
    const myNewElement = document.createElement('input');
    myNewElement.width = siteDocument
    myNewElement.style.fontSize = '2vh';
    counter++
    myNewElement.setAttribute('id', 'myNewElement' + counter)
    console.log(myNewElement.id);
    myNewElement.addEventListener("focus", function doFunctionStuff() {
      changeItem(myNewElement.id)
    }); 
    sheets.appendChild(myNewElement)
    document.getElementById("sheets").style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + window.amountOfColumns +", 1fr)";
  }
}
 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var z = 0; z < inputs.length; z++) {
   inputs[z].style.height = "calc((50vh/" +window.amountOfRows +") - 3px)";
   //inputs[z].style.maxHeight = "calc((80vh/20) - 100px)";
}

/* Fix Issues OR Bugs */
const submitFormula = document.getElementById('submitFormula');

submitFormula.style.fontSize = '1vw';

submitFormula.style.width = '8em';
submitFormula.style.height = '1.5em';

/* Stuff Extra */
/* 

/*  /* Download Excel File

var A = [['n','sqrt(n)']];

for(var j=1; j<10; ++j){ 
    A.push([j, Math.sqrt(j)]);
}

var csvRows = [];

for(var i=0, l=A.length; i<l; ++i){
    csvRows.push(A[i].join(','));
}

var csvString = csvRows.join("%0A");
var a         = document.createElement('a');
a.href        = 'data:attachment/csv,' +  encodeURIComponent(csvString);
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'myFile.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

*/
```

```css
#titletext {
  font-size: 5vh;
}

#sheets {
  display: grid;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#buttons > button {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 4vh;
  font-size: 2vh;
}
#itemVisible {
  width: 8vw;
}
#enterFormula {
  width: 8vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="popup"></div>
    <h1 id="titletext">Excel Sheets</h1>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="" onclick="">File</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Insert</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Page Layout</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Formulas</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Review</button>
      <button id="" onclick="showProperties()">Properties</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Developer</button>
      <button id="" onclick="">Help</button>
    </div> <br>
    <div id="toolresult"></div>
    <div id="item">
      <input id="itemVisible" disabled></input>
      <input id="enterFormula"></input>
      <input type="submit" id="submitFormula"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="sheets" onchange="getItem()"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```